# How to view existing classes in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

for example if I want to view the class Integer in eclipse, how do I get to it? 
I know that there is a method to do it from the code itself for example if I write Integer d = 3; there is a bind i can use and view the class Integer, I just can't find it. Anyone knows what I am talking about ?

Comment: You will need to attach to source code that comes with the JDK, it's a zip archive.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the cursor within "Integer" and press **F3**. Alternatively, you can **Navigate**->**Open Type** in the menu bar (or usually press Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+T) and that will display a "type search" window. There you just start typing the name of the class you want to jump to. You can even enter strings such as NPE there ... which would be looking for any class with those uppercase letters (often referred to as "camel case"), like NullPointerException for example.

That will "jump into" any known class in what's considered the current `Java Build Path`.

If source code is available, you can thus look into Integer.java.

If source code is missing, you will look at something like, but not exactly, de-assembled byte code.

The latter can happen if your project / workspace setup is missing the source files for libraries. In such cases, you have to go into your project setup and manually add source code. (most libraries come with extra zip files containing the Java sources; and those zip files can be added to the library definition in Eclipse). Since Eclipse it will show you whatever copy is on the current selection's `Java Build Path`, if you're developing with Java, having that be a JDK will allow its sources to appear automatically. It's best to have the **Installed JREs** preference page only point to JDKs if you can.